# How to have a Treeview on different tables using data binding

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, xaml, treeview

I would like to create a tree view with the first level bound to "Customer" (id int, name nvarchar, surname nvarchar) and the child nodes bound to other tables "Order" (customer_id int, id int, o_date date, code nvarchar) and another one "Cases" (customer_id int, id int, c_date date, issue nvarchar).

If in Customer I have

```
ID Name Surname
1  Joe  Doe
2  Jim  White
```

and in Order

```
Customer_ID ID o_date       code
1           1  01/01/2019   o001
1           2  01/01/2019   o002
2           3  01/01/2019   o003
```

Cases

```
Customer_ID ID c_date       code
2           1  01/01/2019   issue 001
```

I expect to see

```
Joe Doe
  - o001
  - o002
Jim White
  - o003
  + issue 001
```

Comment: TreeView is a hierarchical control and does __not__ lend itself easily to databinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the table.  Also may need to use a Left Outer Join.  See : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable customerTable = new DataTable();
            customerTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            customerTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            customerTable.Columns.Add("Surname", typeof(string));

            customerTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, "Joe", "Doe"});
            customerTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, "Jim", "White"});

            DataTable orderTable = new DataTable();
            orderTable.Columns.Add("Customer_ID", typeof(int));
            orderTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            orderTable.Columns.Add("o_date", typeof(DateTime));
            orderTable.Columns.Add("code", typeof(string));

            orderTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 1, DateTime.Parse("01/01/2019"), "o001"});
            orderTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 2, DateTime.Parse("01/01/2019"), "o002"});
            orderTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, 3, DateTime.Parse("01/01/2019"), "o003"});

            DataTable caseTable = new DataTable();
            caseTable.Columns.Add("Customer_ID", typeof(int));
            caseTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            caseTable.Columns.Add("o_date", typeof(DateTime));
            caseTable.Columns.Add("code", typeof(string));

            caseTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, 1, DateTime.Parse("01/01/2019"), "issue 001"});

            var results = (from cust in customerTable.AsEnumerable()
                           join order in orderTable.AsEnumerable() on cust.Field<int>("ID") equals order.Field<int>("ID")
                           join caseT in caseTable.AsEnumerable() on cust.Field<int>("ID") equals caseT.Field<int>("ID")
                           select new { cust = cust, order = order, caseT = caseT })
                           .ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, ok this is how to extract them in a single view but this means the Treeview has to be bound to results? and how to discriminate among the type?

Comment: I did not create any bindings.  I just joined the tables.  The views and bindings are left to you.  You can create one or more views.

Comment: jdweng, this is very good but the part I find more difficult is how to do the XAML binding

Comment: You need to create a new query and select the properties you want to bind.  So the query would look like this var bindData = results.Select(x => new { id = x.cust.Field<int>("ID"), o_date = x.caseT<DateTime>("o_date")  });